# ‘should’ versus ‘expected to’

Tags: meaning, nuance, should

I have the following piece of college regulation.

> Staff and students should have access to teaching rooms on the hour. Allowing time for setting up equipment and finding seats, this means that formal teaching would be expected to start at five minutes past the hour and finish at five minutes to the hour, to ensure that the room can be emptied by the hour.

In this paragraph, which of the two clauses is closer to an imperative:

1. ‘should have access to’

or

2. ‘would be expected to’

In other words, would it go against the spirit of the article if the lecturer finished the teaching at say, two minutes to the hour, but he or she managed to leave the room with all the students by the hour, leaving it empty for the next group?

Comment: The first. "Should" implies "must". Would implies a regular occurrence.

Comment: In this context alone, both phrases mean You must do this, but politely. Your plan sounds like *If 5 is kinda wanted, is 4 good enough?*

Comment: @Greybeard So, in simple terms, does the first clause carry more weight than the second?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Could you please explain why both phrases mean ‘you must do this’ in this context alone?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin If you read the article carefully, and dwell on its finer nuance, it is clearly giving more weight to the need for the rooms to be emptied by the hour rather than the need for teaching to stop at five minutes to the hour. Indeed, this seems to be the whole purpose of stipulating the five to five ‘til condition- in order to ensure the rooms are empty at the hour mark. So, if the lecturer manages to finish at three minutes to, and empties the room by the hour mark, then he is not going against the provision of the article. This is my understanding.

Comment: Your use of on the hour and by the hour don't work in that paragraph. You only need five minutes, not ten minutes. "should have access to" and "would be expected to" have no relationship to each other.

Comment: 'Would be expected to' carries two hedging devices in at least one possible reading; 'are expected to' sounds more like 'should' here. But as usual, there will be rule creep. "Sorry; we overran a few minutes." Interpretation of rules is usually the recourse of the infractor (though the 'he or she [still] managed to leave the room with all the students by the hour, leaving it empty for the next group' accomplishment is surely by far the most important factor, making witch-hunts suspicious).

Comment: @Lambie Please explain- so what you are saying is that one can not compare the obligatory weights of “should have access to” and “would be expected to” because they are unrelated to each other?

Comment: Right, they have different meanings. They are not "versions". In any case, I would use classrooms, not teaching rooms. Staff and students must have access to classrooms on the hour.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thanks for your thoughts. I just think that if one wanted to make ‘are expected to’ sound like ‘should’ then one could simply replace the second clause by ‘should’, so as to avoid any ambiguity of meaning.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, taken in isolation, they are unrelated. But in the context of the passage, surely they are related? For example, one could have a situation where a lecture finished at 12:57, thus violating provision (2), but everyone managed to leave the room by 13:00, thereby complying with provision (1)? Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: @Moonwalker Yes. The first (should) is the essential command, from which the idea of the rooms being unoccupied once an hour flows.  Without the "should" command, nothing else will work.

Comment: The discussion shows that this is a matter of opinion, although based on a well-known issue of the implications of *would* and *should*. With so much opinion, I vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

When does *should* suggest, because you're expected to, and when does it obligate?

—Numbers below (#X) refer to [the MW definitions for **should** as a nice idea, a probability, or a euphemism for **must**.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should)

**Suggestion (#2)**

*I should stay quiet, but gossip is fun.*

**Pressured suggestion (#2)**

*The ‘tyranny of the shoulds’ is a stressful nagging.*

**Authoritative obligation (#4)**

*Applications should be submitted well in advance.* Ignore that at your risk, but you may get lucky.

**Bureaucratic obligation (#5)**

*Students **should** have access* equals MUST HAVE access when administrations or authorities post such rules. No wiggle room is offered. Try anything less and see how far that gets you, arguing that *should* is a mere suggestion.

**Bureaucratic obligation (#5)**

*Teaching **would be expected to** … finish at five minutes to the hour* equals MUST do that, with the explanation added as an afterthought.
Ah, but in a perfect world, we’d cover what’s needed in our own fashion and timing. We’d then choose that hill to die on, and lose our job to a petty fight. But we were right, you know.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I appreciate your thoughts. But I must disagree with you. I fully agree that the auxiliary verb ‘should’ in the article refers to an obligatory necessity. But where I disagree is in how to interpret the clause ‘would be expected to’, which uses a different verb. The crux, the emphasis, of the whole passage is on the fact that the teaching rooms are to be emptied by the hour mark. And the provision to have the lectures finished by five minutes to the hour is an expectation- not an obligation, and as such carries significantly less imperative weight.

Comment: I like when folks agree with me and not the other part. Is your argument about three minutes as opposed to five? You may be right!

Comment: Yes, in effect.) It’s just that if the two clauses are meant to carry the same obligatory weight (#5), then they would need to use the same auxiliary verb ‘should’. I have been thinking about this passage for some time, and the more time I dwell on it, the more convinced I become that I am right.) The initial reason for my question was to understand the nuance of a piece of regulation (namely the above) at the university where I teach.

Comment: What I should have written is that if the two clauses are meant to carry the same obligatory weight (#5), then they would need to use the same auxiliary verb ‘should’, without the verb ‘expect’ for the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

*Should* indicates a mild obligation here; it’s not as command-y as *must*.

*Would be expected* means *would be anticipated* or *would be imagined* here. It’s not a command.

It’s the *would* that is “used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful.”
<sub>([*Cambridge Dictionary* — would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would))</sub>

It’s the *expect* that means “to think or believe something will happen, or someone will arrive.”
<sub>([*Cambridge Dictionary* — expect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expect))</sub>

If you put the clause in the active voice, you can better see that it is not a command but rather conjecture about the number of minutes it takes to set up and empty out:

> **Passive**: *Formal teaching would be expected to start at five minutes
> past the hour and finish at five minutes to the hour.*
>
> **Active**: *[We] would expect formal teaching to start at five minutes
> past the hour and finish at five minutes to the hour.*
>
> **Passive**: *Formal teaching would be imagined to start at five minutes
> past the hour and finish at five minutes to the hour.*
>
> **Active**: *[We] would imagine formal teaching to start at five minutes past the
> hour and finish at five minutes to the hour.*